# Не понимаю программу с вложенным циклом для поиска простых чисел до n-числа

Tags: c#, циклы

Помогите разобраться с работой кода на c# для поиска простых чисел. Не до конца понимаю как он работает и, вследствие этого, что нужно дописать

```
using System;
namespace lab_1
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int d = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i= i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        d += 1;
                    }
                }
                if (d == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какое место не понятное?

Comment: Ну программа неоптимальная, однако выглядит рабочей. Вы знаете определение простых чисел?

Comment: Определение я знаю, просто не понимаю как мне этот вложенный цикл написать

Comment: @jockk алгоритм неправильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код ищет простые числа "по определению" - т.е. выводит те числа `i`, у которых только два делителя - 1 и i (количество делителей - `d`).

Две ошибки - `d=0` нужно внести внутрь внешнего цикла, и поправить `i= i++`

Вот рабочий код:

```
 static void Main() {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                int d = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        d += 1;
                    }
                }
                if (d == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
```

Однако более оптимально проверять делители от 2 до корня из числа

```
static void Main() {
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                int prime = 1;
                for (int j = 2; j*j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        prime = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (prime == 1) {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                
            }

   10: 2 3 5 7
```

Comment: спасибо большущее вам!!

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
          if (i % j == 0) //-- ошибка
            {
                d += 1;
            }
        }
        if (d == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

4 % 2 = 0, но 4 - это не простое число. так что условие неправильное.

UPD: Да вообще все неправильное. Вот:

```
using System;
namespace lab_1
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int count = 0;
            bool usl = false;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                usl = true;
                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    var rem = (double)i / (double)j;
                    rem = rem - Math.Truncate(rem);
                    if (rem == 0)
                    {
                        usl = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (usl)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine(i); //-- Выводим простое число
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count); //-- выводим количество простых чисел -1 (единица не учитывается)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а в чем разница (i % j) от ((i % j))?

Comment: @OwDafuq скорее всего ни в чем, моя привычка окучивать условия, ты прав. Но алгоритм автора все равно неправильный))) я написал свой на его основе

Comment: тогда лучше убрать это замечание из ответа, чтобы не вводить ТСа в заблуждение :)

Comment: @OwDafuq ок. Приведенный **мной** алгоритм не оптимизирован по используемым функциям - делал на коленке - претензии не принимаю, готов пояснить.